# Select data with like operator in yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

How can i retrieve data with `Like` operator?
I have tried this but getting an error:

```
    use yii\db\Query;
    public function getExportData($searchVal = '')
    {
         $query = new Query;
         if($searchVal != '') { **here i am getting error when searchVall != ''**   
             $query->select('*')->from('post')
             ->where(['like', 'title', $searchVal])
             ->orderBy(['added_date_time' => SORT_DESC]);
             $posts = $query->createCommand()->queryAll();
         } else {
             $query->select('*')->from('post')->orderBy(['added_date_time' => SORT_DESC]);
             $posts = $query->createCommand()->queryAll();
         }
         return $posts;
     }
```

Is there any simple way for select statement?

Comment: What error do You get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass the query using variable then use findBySql() method.
For example,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `post` where `title` LIKE 'foo%' ";
$result = Model::findBySql($query)->all();
```

Hope this will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 18):

Try something like this :

```
    $query = Post::find();
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $searchVal])
         ->orderBy(['added_date_time' => SORT_DESC])
         ->all();
```

Comment: is there any way that we write query in variable and pass that variable?

Comment: You can use dataprovider https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/output-data-providers.md

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".YourModel::tableName()." where title LIKE :param";
$result = YourModel::findBySql($query, [':param' => $param.'%'])->all();
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

See [official documentation about where operator format](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-query-builder.md#operator-format-).